# drush sql-dump asking for password

Tags: drush

Whenever I run drush sql-dump it will prompt me for the database password. Is there a way that this can be done automatically? I don't quite understand why its not just reading this from settings.php

When I do a drush status --show-passwords it is shown there.

I ask because I want to script db backups to happen via drush. Any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I presume you are using postgres.

psql, the commandline tool that Drush uses to manipulate the database, has no provision to pass a password as a commandline option, so Drush cannot provide it even if it knows what it is.  You may set up a .pgpass file in your $HOME directory to supply the password; it should contain entries that look like this:

```
localhost:5432:*:www-data:PASSWORD
```

If you create this file, and insure that it is chmod 600, then psql will no longer prompt for the password.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Yes, this is a postgres site. I got around the issue by putting trust as an auth method in pg_hba.conf. Thanks for your help.